# JAVA SQL - INSERT on multiple VALIDATION into new table , validations done on existing tables

Tags: java, validation, plsql, insert, conditional-statements

Validation 1 - check to see whether or not a radio button is checked.

Validation 2 - check to see if record already exists, if not - goto validation 2

Validation 3- check a field to determine if value meets criteria - if it does - insert record

If all three conditions are met, then the record can be inserted into DB.

This is done with NetBeans and Oracle

I know a query cannot be written for the Radio Button Validation - this will be the first part of the validation actions performed. If radio button not checked, send message, end validation, do not insert record.

I need a query that will take the value from the end result Table, cross reference with 2 values from other tables, where one is the PK, the other value is a varchar. If the varchar exists with matching PK, the new record cannot be inserted. Also, multiple records cannot be inserted unless a condition of another tables value is met.

Can this be achieved with one SQL statement? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Typically, validation occurs in the user interface layer.  So, all validations are checked prior to starting the work in a service that has a transaction.  Then in general, you pray that nothing happens between validation and when you actually make your service call, if it does you raise an exception.  Another way I've seen this done is just to make the sql statement and see if an exception occurs and hope your constraints on your database are right.  Finally, take a look at [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html).

Comment: Would you be able to supply me with some typical validation syntax? Example -  resultSet.method() or queries which would facilitate my needs. I am really quite new and don't know where to begin. I know how to establish connections, prepare and create queries with result sets of corresponding UI.

Comment: That is a daunting request.  Is this for school or work?